# Problema com conexão entre EF e PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, aplicação-web, web.config

Estou tentando realizar uma conexão com EF e PostgreSQL em uma aplicação Asp.Net Mvc

Estou utilizando as seguintes referencias

- EntityFramework6.Npgsql
- Npgsql 3.1
- .NET Framework 4.5

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Categoria
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Descricao { get; set; }
   public int Status { get; set; }
 }

public class MeuNegocioContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet <Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // do not use migration
        Database.SetInitializer<MeuNegocioContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>().ToTable("Categoria", "public");
    }

}
```

E meu Web.Config fica dessa está dessa forma
http://pastebin.com/QNmSSAyU

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MeuNegocioContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=meunegocioweb;User Id=postgres;Password=6844866;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Porém ocorre um erro quando eu tento executar a seguinte função

```
 // GET: Categorias
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return View(db.Categorias.ToList());
  }
```

An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Npgsql.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: O inicializador de tipo de 'Npgsql.Counters' acionou uma exceção.

Qual seria o problema relacionado ao meu WebConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece alguma incompatibilidade de versão das assemblies. Tente atualizar todas referencias via nuget. Utilizo configurações um pouco diferentes no webconfig, se ajudar segue:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Também consegui resolver esse problema atraves do seguinte link http://duanbrito.net/2016/06/07/postgresql-npgsql-entityframework-6-com-net-framework-4-5/